# addEventListener input keycode not working

Tags: javascript

Is there a way of getting the Keycode that is being pressed when `addEventListener input`is fired?

```
<p contentEditable="true" id="newTask">New task</p>

document.getElementById("newTask").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13)
            {
                console.log("input event fired");
                // return false; // returning false will prevent the event from bubbling up.
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("others: " + e);
                // return true;
            }
        }, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you should be using the `keypress` event, rather than `input`.

Try the following:

```
document.getElementById("newTask").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13)
        {
            console.log("input event fired");
            // return false; // returning false will prevent the event from bubbling up.
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("others: " + e);
            // return true;
        }
    }, false);
```

Comment: I am aware of the Keypress, but keypress does not cater copy-paste content.

Comment: so bind two events

Comment: Since I am unable to  find any solution online it looks like it is is not possible to do it with input event.